# How is your position on the Clash of Clans war map determined.?

Tags: clash-of-clans

At first I thought it was by trophies, because I am the top 6th player in our clan, and I'm 7th on the war base but that's not it. And I have previously been the top 2nd of trophies, but like 13th on the war map. And then some other forums said it was based on your village level or something? But there's at least two people below me that have better villages than me. They have better walls, and stuff. So now I'm confused.

Comment: That's a good question, I will look into it

Answer (score 3):

The bases are ordered from highest to lowest strength. Strength is based on each member’s attacking power (troops, army camp capacity, spells and heroes) and defensive strength (defense buildings, walls, traps and heroes).Walls have no effect on the clan war position.The total cost spent on Defense and attack is taken into account.